# Logout using Retrofit in Android

Tags: android, retrofit

I have to log out from my app.

This is my `php` script:

```
public function logoutAction(Request $request){
   $requestData=json_decode($request->getContent(),1);
   $em=$this->get('doctrine')->getEntityManager();
   if(isset($requestData['token'])){
       if($userToken=$em->getRepository('NavZUserBundle:UserToken')->findOneBy(array('token'=>$requestData['token']))){
           $em->remove($userToken);
           $em->flush($userToken);
           $response['status']='success';
           $response['msg']="Logged out successfully";
       }else{
           $response['status']='fail';
           $response['msg']="Mobile User is already logged out";
       }
   }else{
       $response['status']='fail';
       $response['msg']="Missing required parameter";
   }
   return new JsonResponse($response);
}
```

This is api call using `POST` parameter:

```
@POST("api/logout/")
Call<ApiResponse> logOutUser(@Query("token") String token);
```

I have button for logout .

```
@OnClick(R.id.tv_signout)
void onSignOut(View view) {
    logOutMethod();
}
private void logOutMethod() {
    ApiService apiService = RestClient.getClient();
    Call<ApiResponse> logOut = apiService.logOutUser(getPreference().getToken());
    Log.e(TAG, "logOutMethod one: "+getPreference().getToken());
    Log.e(TAG, "logOutMethod two: "+logOut );
    logOut.enqueue(new Callback<ApiResponse>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Response<ApiResponse> response) {
            if (response.isSuccess()){
                ApiResponse result = response.body();
                if (result.getData() != null){
                    goToLogInActivity();
                    Snackbar.make(findViewById(android.R.id.content), result.getMsg(), Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }else {
                    Snackbar.make(findViewById(android.R.id.content), result.getMsg(), Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }else {
                Snackbar.make(findViewById(android.R.id.content), response.message(), Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Throwable t) {

        }
    });
}
private void goToLogInActivity(){
    getPreference().removeLoginPreferences();
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class);
    finish();
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
    overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

After debug:

```
E/SettingsActivity: logOutMethod one: f7177163c833dff4b38fc8d2872f1ec658940cbf280ce
E/SettingsActivity: logOutMethod two: retrofit2.ExecutorCallAdapterFactory$ExecutorCallbackCall@ca3eb18
```

But in part:

```
ApiResponse result = response.body();
```

The method `response.body()` throws:

```
data = null
msg = "Missing required parameter"
status = "fail"
```

And in my app also throws  `SnackBar` message `Missing required parameter` and app does not get logout.

What can I do for logout using POST method? What can be done here?

Answer (score 0):

I think you may not get "token" value on

```
 Call<ApiResponse> logOut = apiService.logOutUser(new PreferenceTypes(this).getToken());
```

Please check if you are clearing preferences before making API call for logout.

Comment: Ahhh, I think too that. Any idea to setup the token of login user for logout ?

Comment: Did you trace token value app side as well in script on server at line 

`logoutAction(Request $request)`

Comment: It's all about token. Token is null in the result: `result.getData().getToken()` is resulting null. But, `response.body` display result.

Comment: Just take JSON response using `HttpLoggingInterceptor` with retrofit and copy that JSON string to http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org generate model class and use it with your project.

Comment: Thanks for this. In `logOut` method, after debug, I am getting a token via `getPreference().getToken()`. But I think problem is with `response.body`.

Answer (score 0):

My mistake: I am trying to parse the `@query()` instead of `@Body`.

This is how I solved my probelm:

I have to submit the `token` in `json` format. So, I implement my Log Out API using as follows:

Now, the API call using `POST` method as:

```
@POST("/api/logout/")
Call<ApiResponse> logOutUser(@Body TokenJsonObject tokenJsonObject);
```

`TokenJsonObject` model class:

```
public class TokenJsonObject {

    public TokenJsonObject(String token) {
        this.token = token;
    }

    @SerializedName("token")
    private String token;

    public String getToken() {
        return token;
    }

    public void setToken(String token) {
        this.token = token;
    }
}
```

And finally, After `sign_out` button click:

```
 @OnClick(R.id.tv_signout)
void onSignOut(View view) {
    logOutMethod();
}

private void logOutMethod() {
    ApiService apiService = RestClient.getClient();
    Call<ApiResponse> logOut = apiService.logOutUser(new TokenJsonObject(getPreference().getToken()));
    logOut.enqueue(new Callback<ApiResponse>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Response<ApiResponse> response) {
            if (response.isSuccess()) {
                ApiResponse result = response.body();
                if (result.getData() != null) {
                    Snackbar.make(findViewById(android.R.id.content), result.getMsg(), Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else {
                    goToLogInActivity();
                    Snackbar.make(findViewById(android.R.id.content), result.getMsg(), Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            } else {
                Snackbar.make(findViewById(android.R.id.content), response.message(), Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Throwable t) {

        }
    });
}

private void goToLogInActivity() {
    getPreference().removeLoginPreferences();
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class);
    finish();
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
    overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```